# Strange alignment behavior of two numbered equations on the same line

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, tabularx, alignment

Considering my previous question at this link [One or more equations (two-by-two on different rows) with an enumerate to the left and the another on the right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503822/one-or-more-equations-two-by-two-on-different-rows-with-an-enumerate-to-the-le), I have a strange alignment behavior of two numbered equations on the same line. In other words there is an overhang between the (0.0-3) and (0.0-4) equations.

How can the problem be corrected?

Here there is the MWE and the relative output:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,
            left=3.2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %%%%%%%%%%% <--------- added 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqnnumsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\reflectbox{\ding{228}}}}

\makeatletter
\newtagform{bbrackets}% <name>
  [\textbf]% Internal style
  {(}% Left bracket
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
     \eqnnumsymbol%
   \else
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
       \eqnnumsymbol%
     \fi
   \fi
   )}% Right bracket
\makeatother
\usetagform{bbrackets}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5][2-3]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
\begin{equation}
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y),
\label{eqn:1}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
f(ax) = af(x),\,
x,y\in V, a\in\mathbb{C}
\label{eqn:2}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[6][8-9]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
\begin{equation}
\overline{E}= -\overline \nabla \varphi-\frac{\partial \overline{A}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:3}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
\overline{B}=\overline \nabla \times\overline{A}
\label{eqn:4}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: unrelated note you are missing `\noindent` before the `\begin{tabularx}` (see the 15pt warnings in the log) and you declare three columns but only use two.

Comment: It is not clear what other behaviour you expect, one equation is taller than the other so it takes more vertical space, you would see the same if it was an image of a tikzpicture or anything else, not just equations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm absolutely agree with you on `\noindent`. Into my structure there is no this problem. After I have `@{}XXX@{}` used directly the code from Stefan Kottwitz's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33433/how-to-place-and-number-3-short-equations-in-one-line

Comment: You can fake the height with `vphantom`: `\overline{B}=\overline \nabla \times\overline{A}\vphantom{-\frac{\partial \overline{A}}{\partial t}}`.

Comment: Stefan used `XXX` as he had three equations per line, so three columns in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really expect these to be aligned as they have different sizes, however you can get a bit closer if you use `m` rather than `p` columns. I use `tabular` here as `tabularx` isn't really helping as you know in advance given `XX` that there will be two equal columns, so you may as well specify that directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,
            left=3.2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %%%%%%%%%%% <--------- added 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqnnumsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\reflectbox{\ding{228}}}}

\makeatletter
\newtagform{bbrackets}% <name>
  [\textbf]% Internal style
  {(}% Left bracket
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
     \eqnnumsymbol%
   \else
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
       \eqnnumsymbol%
     \fi
   \fi
   )}% Right bracket
\makeatother
\usetagform{bbrackets}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5][2-3]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{m{.5\textwidth}@{}}}
\begin{equation}
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y),
\label{eqn:1}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
f(ax) = af(x),\,
x,y\in V, a\in\mathbb{C}
\label{eqn:2}
\end{equation}
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[6][8-9]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{m{.5\textwidth}@{}}}
\begin{equation}
\overline{E}= -\overline \nabla \varphi-\frac{\partial \overline{A}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:3}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
\overline{B}=\overline \nabla \times\overline{A}
\label{eqn:4}
\end{equation}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much to @David Carlisle and @Marijn that with your comments I have had another possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm,
            left=3.2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %%%%%%%%%%% <--------- added 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Change number equations with sections
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqnnumsymbol}{\textcolor{ocre}{\reflectbox{\ding{228}}}}

\makeatletter
\newtagform{bbrackets}% <name>
  [\textbf]% Internal style
  {(}% Left bracket
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{equation}=0
     \eqnnumsymbol%
   \else
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{align}=0
       \eqnnumsymbol%
     \fi
   \fi
   )}% Right bracket
\makeatother
\usetagform{bbrackets}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[5][2-3]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\begin{equation}
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y),
\label{eqn:1}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
f(ax) = af(x),\,
x,y\in V, a\in\mathbb{C}
\label{eqn:2}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[6][8-9]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\begin{equation}
\overline{E}= -\overline \nabla \varphi-\frac{\partial \overline{A}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:3}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}
\overline{B}=\overline \nabla \times\overline{A}\vphantom{-\frac{\partial \overline{A}}{\partial t}}
\label{eqn:4}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```